# Running Thunderbird 3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

How do I run Thunderbird 3 which I downloaded? Well, I can get it to run by executing the Thunderbird shell script file. However that creates a terminal windows as well and will close Thunderbird if it is closed.

I am running Ubuntu 9.10.

How do I get it to open without the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say what version of Ubuntu you're running, but have you tried installing it from the packages so that it installs a menu entry for you?

Exactly how you do this depends on the version of Ubuntu, but from a command prompt `sudo aptitude install thunderbird` will probably work, or try [these instructions](http://digitizor.com/2009/12/10/how-to-install-thunderbird-3-shredder-in-ubuntu-9-10/) or [these instructions](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-thunderbird-3-in-ubuntu-9-109-048-108-04.html) I found via Google.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. Unfortunately from the command prompt, it installs Thunderbird 2.x

Comment: Then try the alternative instructions I provided ;)  Both detail how to install Thunderbird 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the steps from [this site](http://digitizor.com/2009/12/10/how-to-install-thunderbird-3-shredder-in-ubuntu-9-10/):

1. Add the Mozilla PPA in your source list using:

   ```
   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
   ```
2. Update source list using:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install Thunderbird 3 using:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install thunderbird-3.0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I installed T-Bird 3 myself and I run it like this:

```
/opt/product/thunderbird/thunderbird
```

where `/opt/product/thunderbird` is the directory I installed to.  That works fine for me with no terminal window.  However, if I were to do this again I would instead install using the [Ubuntuzilla project](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ubuntuzilla/index.php?title=Main_Page) @ Source Forge.  I used this to get Firefox 3.6 with no problems.  The only downside is that I can't upgrade FireFox from within FireFox; I have to use the `Update Manager` to do it (though I do get notified from within FireFox).